# How to find out which parent URL called my script?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, referrer

I have created a page for a web banner under http://example.com/banner, I'm sending this link to publisher websites and pay them to run it.

However, some publishers run, some are not and I'd like to find which parent URL'S called for this page or where did the click come from. Generally, they are putting this URL in an iframe to serve it.

(Many pages doesn't pass referral parameter.)

I've tried different approaches with JS and PHP but as you might guess I'm getting http://example.com/banner as the parent URL.

Is there a way to know the parent URL from a different domain with PHP, JS or any other piece of code? I have a list of publishers but I also need to know which websites running the banner except for those sites.

To make it more clear here is a schema:

> MY PAGE WITH BANNER > MY PUBLISHER WEBSITE > USER VISITING THE
>   PUBLISHER
>
> I don't want to get IP of the user visiting my publisher's website or my page's
>   URL. I want to see URL of my publisher's website which is in between.

Since this is my web server I can read access logs, error logs etc. without issues.

I'm open to any suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: possibly using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and store that into a database when someone goes to you page?

Comment: use js instead, then it would be trivial to get the url and append it as a parm/cookie when fetching the image/banner.. else you're stuck with the above which is unreliable.

Comment: I think this doesn't work when parent URL blocks all http referer header requests for the web browser. And generally, they do block this requests. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Avi, HTTP Referrer is not really for that. I guess the OP means REMOTE_ADDR / REMOTE_HOST. Try dumping out $_SERVER in PHP. Or look into the logging mechanism of your web-server.

Comment: @Lawrence, can you be more specific about this? I've tried different JS codes but every time they showed me my website's URL or showed nothing at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, host a javascript file on your server.

Then they would place the script anywhere they want to put the banner:

```
<script src="//yoursite.com/banner.js"></script>
```

You could use params in that URL to then serve custom js.

Then *fundamentally* the code would look something like the following which injects the banner into the DOM where ever the script is placed. You get the sites URL from `window.location.href` and then send it as a param when requesting the image. (You could also use cookies etc)

```html
<script>
  // inject an anchoring element
  document.write('<div class="banner_ad"></div>');
  // find it
  var parentDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("banner_ad");
  // create the img/banner, notice the site param
  var banner = document.createElement("img");
  banner.src = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?site=' + encodeURI(window.location.href);

  // loop over the parent elements of each anchoring element
  for (var i = 0, len = parentDiv.length; i < len; i++) {
    // create the link
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.appendChild(banner);
    link.setAttribute('title', 'Ads by Foobar');
    link.setAttribute('href', 'http://example.com');
    // inject the link and img
    parentDiv[i].parentNode.appendChild(link);
  }
</script>
```

Then server-side, look for the `$_GET['site']` param.

It's not foolproof, nothing is.